# Rails delayed_job startup start/stop capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, delayed-job

As I've read somewhere, to start delayed_jobs with the server startup, I should write in config/deploy.rb the following:

```
require "delayed/recipes"

set :rails_env, "production" #added for delayed job

namespace :delayed_job do
  desc "Start delayed_job process" 
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job start #{rails_env}" 
  end

  desc "Stop delayed_job process" 
  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job stop #{rails_env}" 
  end

  desc "Restart delayed_job process" 
      task :restart, :roles => :app do
        run "cd #{current_path}; script/delayed_job restart #{rails_env}" 
  end
end

after "deploy:start", "delayed_job:start" 
after "deploy:stop", "delayed_job:stop" 
after "deploy:restart", "delayed_job:restart"
```

It's not working. In fact, I thought that this file did existed previowsly, but it wasn't (I creaded it).
So what should I do to keep it working?

And more questions, what should I do to stop/restart the processing of jobs during the web execution?

Answer (score 0):

just try:

```
desc "Restart delayed_job process"
    task :restart, :roles => :app do
     run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec script/delayed_job restart #{rails_env}"
end
```

this should work.

Comment: The problem is that the file is not being called.
`puts "DEPLOY FILE"` for example, is not being showed, and the jobs are not executed.